# Как выбрать записи с датой меньше указанной

Tags: mysql

Как выбрать записи с датой меньше указанной из таблицы в mysql . Тип поля с датой   varchar, фомат даты 01.10.2015.

Comment: переделайте поле на тип date. тогда все будет тривиально. А так вам всегда придется приводить дату к какому нибудь более удобному формату прямо в запросе - а это гарантирует, что любой простейший запрос будет искать полным перебором таблицы, что самым печальным образом скажется на скорости работы

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно это сделать:

```
SELECT * FROM demo d WHERE STR_TO_DATE(d.date, '%d.%m.%Y') <= '20151003'
```

Comment: Так не выбирает

Comment: @Виталий Странно, у меня сработала выборка.  Можете подкинуть пару записей из вашей таблицы?

Comment: Извиняюсь, разобрался.Просто в запросе надо было использовать период между двумя датами. Ваш пример правильный, спасибо.

Comment: @Виталий  - фух отлично, а то я уже испугался.